# Maven dependency to jar in Nexus

Tags: java, maven, dependencies, nexus

How can I add a dependency to a jar, which is in my private maven repository?

I have a private nexus repository, say: https://localhost/repository/my-team/

In one project, I generate, compile and pack to a jar some java classes. say, `my.jar`.
Then I upload it to nexus as a jar:

```sh
curl --upload-file my.jar \ 
     "https://localhost/repository/my-team/com/example/artifact/my.jar"
```

In another project I want to refer to this jar as a dependency:

```
<repositories>
     <repository>
        <id>nexus</id>
        <url>https://localhost/repository/my-team/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

**How can I add a dependency** in this case? Where do I specify the url to that jar file?

Comment: Use Maven to build your jar files and upload them to Nexus ...it makes it easier ...do not do ti via curl etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Maven, you don't handle jars by urls, but by GAVs (GroupId, ArtifactId, Version).

You don't upload it with curl, but you use `mvn deploy` (for building and deploying a jar) or `mvn deploy:deploy-file` if you have a jar already and want to deploy it.

It will be stored using the GAV (or coordinates) given in the `pom.xml`.

You then use the same GAV to reference it as dependency.

Comment: I'd gladly use `mvn deploy` or `mvn deploy:deploy-file`, but I don't have any maven or pom.xml there. Just generate some java code, compile and pack into a jar with `jar cf out/my.jar -C compiled/.`  And the script works in the container whaere maven in not installed. Is there some way around it?

Comment: Yes, but you make your life hard. There is a standard translation from GAV to url parts, which is constructed by writing the groupId with / instead of ., then the artifactId, then the version and then `artifactId-version-classifier.extension`. Furthermore, you need to generate a pom.xml yourself and deploy it as well, because otherwise, Maven projects cannot use that dependency.

Comment: Thank you, that really helped by the end of the day. 
I tried to make a small maven project out of it, but it revealed additional issues, so I decided to go for curl approach. Uploading `groupId/artifactId/version/artifactId-version.jar` and `groupId/artifactId/version/artifactId-version.pom` worked.